# how does P have n generators?

Tags: free-modules

[image]

[image]

This is from Page 101 of Rotman's book on homological algebra.
I am not sure for the proof of ii, why there are as many generators of P as basis elements? Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: The assumption here is $P$ is finitely generated. So, it has $n$ generators for some $n>0$.

Comment: Hi jijijojo, sorry I didn't make the question clear. I meant why the number of generators is the same as the number of the basis elements. Thx very much!

Comment: It’s the other way around: the number of elements in the basis is the same as the number of generators for $P$. It’s the number of generators of $P$ that determines the size of the basis, not the other way around.

Comment: P.S. Please don’t use images; they are not searchable, they may not be displayed properly, and they are not accessible to people who use screen readers.